# NoReverseMatch in Django, but there's a names url pattern for it

Tags: python, django

I'm getting a no NoReverseMatch error in a django app I've just pulled from someone else.  The exact error is

```
NoReverseMatch at /dataupload/
Reverse for ''upload'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

'dataupload' is an app. The main urls.py contains

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^dataupload/', include('dataupload.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The dataupload module is on the PYTHONPATH and `from dataupload import urls` works in the django shell. The dataupload urls.py has the following (leaving some stuff out for brevity)

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^upload/$', views.upload, name='upload'),
    url(r'^upload/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.edit_file, name='updatefile'),
    url(r'^download/(?P<file_id>\d+)/$', views.download_file, name='downloadfile'),  
    ...
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

The offending line in the template is

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href={% url 'upload' %}>Upload</a></li>
<li><a href={% url 'manage_data_list' %}>Manage Data</a></li>
```

As you can see, there is a named view "upload" without arguments, which point s to a view which only accepts a request object and so requires no arguments. Why is this reverse lookup not working?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the right version? Looks like this app is written for Django 1.5+ (the url tag syntax changed then), but you are running na earlier version.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware there was a difference

Comment: Yes, it's the django version. Virtualenv to the rescue

Answer (score -1):

It has to be something like this:

{% url 'upload' something.pk %}.

Your url is looking for an argument, that's why you get that error.